# how to compare the sequence of characters in two strings

Tags: python

Python version is 2.7.9
In python, I have the baseline strings and other strings to be compared:

```
baseline_string="c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10"
#all the characters appeared as the sequence defined in base line string ,this is ok
compared1="c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10" 
#all the characters appeared as the sequence defined in base line string,some charaters don't appear such as c2 and c7 don't appear ,this is ok
compared2="c1,c3,c4,c5,c6,c8,c9,c10"
#some character does not appear as the defind sequece,such as c4 is before c3 ,and c110 is before c9
```

The difflib.SequenceMatcher can not solve my problem.
Need the python guru to give some advice.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: compared3="c1,c4,c3,c5,c6,c8,c10,c9"

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: do you want the string matching percentage? Or the elements not in the current list?

Comment: import sys, os

def validate_sequence(base_str,candidate_str):

    if 'very sub string sequence of candidate string is less than the seqeunce defined as base_str':

        return True
    else:
        return False
if __name__ == '__main__':

    compared1 = "c1,c2,c3,c4,c5"

    compared2 = "c1,c3,c4"

    compared3 = "c4,c3"

    #check1_2 should be True

    check1_2 = validate_sequence(compared1, compared2)

    # check1_3 should be False,because c4 should be after c3

    check1_3 = validate_sequence(compared1, compared3)

Comment: @ Vasu Deo.S
Elements not in the current list is easy to check.
I want to check the character order. the order of character shoulde follow the order as defined
such as :c4 should after c1 and c2  and c3.
some characters can not appear,such as  c1,c4,c5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# the following code is run ok,but I think that should be better
#method to check
def check_order():
    from collections import OrderedDict
    compared1 = "c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,"
    compared2 = "c1,c3,c4,c5,c6,c8,c9,c10"
    compared2 = "c3,c4,c6,c5,c9,c10,c7"
    compared3 = "c4,c3,c6,c5,c8,c9,c10"
    base_dict = OrderedDict()
    base_order = 1
    compared_dict2 = OrderedDict()
    compared_order2 = OrderedDict()
    compare_order2 = 1

    compared_dict3 = OrderedDict()
    compare_order3 = 1
    check_result = True

    for base_substr in compared1.split(','):
        base_dict[base_substr] = base_order
        base_order = base_order + 1

    for base_keys, base_value in base_dict.items():
        print("key is " + str(base_keys) + \
              " order is " + str(base_value))

    for compared_substr2 in compared2.split(','):
        compared_dict2[compared_substr2] = compare_order2
        compared_order2[compare_order2] = compared_substr2
        compare_order2 = compare_order2 + 1

    for compare_key2, compared_value2 in compared_dict2.items():
        print("key is " + str(compare_key2) +\
              " order is " + str(compared_value2))

    compare_len_2 = len(compared_dict2)
    compare_key_tmp = None
    compare_key_order_in_base = 0
    for compare_key2, compared_value2 in compared_dict2.items():
        based_value = base_dict[compare_key2]
        for num in range(1, compared_value2):
            compare_key_tmp = compared_order2[num]
            compare_key_order_in_base = base_dict[compare_key_tmp]
            print("The key :" + str(compare_key_tmp) +\
                  "and order in base is:" + str(compare_key_order_in_base))
            if compare_key_order_in_base <= based_value:
                print("The key " + str(compare_key_tmp) + \
                      "is less than" + str(based_value))
            else:
                print("Error,The key " + str(compare_key_tmp) +\
                      "is larger than" + str(based_value))
                check_result = False

    return check_result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_result = check_order()
    if check_result:
        print("Pass")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the **itertools** will help you overcome the strings being of different lengths.
`.zip` compares character for character in each of the strings and returns them in `tuples`.

```
import itertools

compared1 = "c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10" 

compared2 = "c1,c3,c4,c5,c6,c8,c9,c10"

words = itertools.zip_longest(compared1,compared2,fillvalue=None)

incorrect = len([c for c,d in words if c!=d]) 

print(incorrect)
```